# AccessibleObjectFromPoint() returns an incorrect object

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I am creating a program that selects the object via mouse cursor using AccessibleObjectFromPoint() however it produces an incorrect result.

[I hovered the mouse at this icon but it selects a different icon instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kw4a.png)

Here's my sample code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "oleacc.lib")

HRESULT SelectItemAtPoint(POINT point)
{
    VARIANT varItem;
    IAccessible* pAcc;
    HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromPoint(point, &pAcc, &varItem);
    if ((hr == S_OK))
    {
        hr = pAcc->accSelect((SELFLAG_TAKEFOCUS | SELFLAG_TAKESELECTION), varItem);
        VariantClear(&varItem);
        pAcc->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    while (true)
    {
        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        printf("x: %d y: %d", pt.x, pt.y);
        SelectItemAtPoint(pt);
        Sleep(50);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the image I hovered at Unreal Engine but the program selected MATLAB instead.
I also checked the cursor points.
Any ways how to fix this?

EDIT: I am using Windows 10 Home with Visual Studio 2017

Comment: You probably missed to convert the cursor coordinates to screen coordinates before calling `AccessibleObjectFromPoint()`.

Comment: Isn't `GetCursorPos()` already in screen coordinates?

Comment: Perhaps UnrealEngine does not want to play ball. Or perhaps this is because of DPI scaling.

Comment: In DPI scaling, how do I fix it? I noticed there is an offset when calling the function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I finally figured out how to fix it. Thanks for the DPI Scaling tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from Microsoft documentation:

[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/active-accessibility-and-windows-vista-screen-scaling)

> Microsoft Active Accessibility does not use logical coordinates. The
>   following methods and functions either return physical coordinates or
>   take them as parameters.
>
> - `IAccessible::accHitTest`
> - `IAccessible::accLocation`
> - `AccessibleObjectFromPoint`
>
> By default, an Microsoft Active
>   Accessibility client application running in a non-96-dpi environment
>   will not be able to obtain correct results from these calls. For
>   example, because the cursor position is in logical coordinates, the
>   client cannot simply pass these coordinates to
>   `AccessibleObjectFromPoint` to obtain the element that is under the
>   cursor.
>
> The solution is in two parts:
>
> - Make the client application "dpi-aware". To do this, call the
>     `SetProcessDPIAware` function at startup. This function makes the entire
>     process dpi-aware, meaning that all windows that belong to the process
>     are unscaled.
> - Use functions that are dpi-aware. For example, to get
>     cursor coordinates, call the `GetPhysicalCursorPos` function. Do not use
>     `GetCursorPos`; its behavior in dpi-aware applications is undefined.
>
> If
>   your application performs direct cross-process communication with
>   non-dpi-aware applications, you may have convert between logical and
>   physical coordinates by using the `PhysicalToLogicalPoint` and
>   `LogicalToPhysicalPoint` functions.

So changing `GetCursorPos()` to `GetPhysicalCursorPos()` solved my problem.